# How to initialize lateinit var with 'by keyword' in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-lateinit

I want to initialize lateinit variable with 'by'.

How can I?

```kotlin
lateinit var test: int

fun main() {
    test by something {} // error!
}
```

I tried using by in by lazy, and I tried using by in lateinit var, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `lateinit` when using `by lazy`. Lazy means it'll be initialized the first time it's referenced. `lateinit` means you manually assign a value some time after construction.

So all you need is

```
val test by lazy { something() }

fun main() {
    println(test) // runs the initializer and prints the value
}
```

Update:
Or, if you want to initialize an exising `lateinit` property:

```
lateinit var test: Type
fun main() {
  val someting by other
  test = something
}
```

Comment: No, I don't mean that I want to use the by-lazy keyword and lateinit together, but I want to initialize the variable declared as lateinit through the by keyword.

Comment: @recsater See updated answer. Does that cover it? I don't think it's possible to do it without the intermediate variable.